# Organising data in a Plist correctly

Tags: xcode, dictionary, plist

Im at my wits end here, please assist me you beautiful people!!

My conundrum is this:

I have a list of 100 drugs. Each has a name, each has a URL associated with it, and each is in a section from 1-8. I need to create a list of the drug names in a table view. When a specific drug is selected, the drug name, its section and its URL need to be passed to another view controller.

I know how to implement all the gubbins to pass to another controller, set up table views etc I just dont know how to organise the data in a plist file so it can be accessible within the program and how to keep each drug linked to its URL and section.

Any ideas? ive been messing around with dictionaries, arrays and objects for the best past of 7 hours now. I think I might cry if I dont sort it soon!

Thanks alot,

Lucy

Comment: Is there a reason you're attached to using a plist? It might be simpler to just store the data in a plain text file and then parse it.

Comment: no reason at all - i just presumed this would be the easiest way to organise it - im open to suggestions to get this sucker finished! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
   <dict>
     <key>name</key><string>Drug name</string>
     <key>url</key> <string>http://www.urltodrug.com/Drug%20name</string>
     <key>section</key> <integer>5</integer>
   </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Just add more `<dict>`s and you are done.

To put all into an array:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Drugs" ofType:@"plist"]; 
self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

To sort the array by section and drug name:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.dataArray sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:@[
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"section" ascending:YES],
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]
]];
```

To reduce the array to just show the names:

```
NSArray *namesArray = [sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

Welcome to the power of `NSDictionary` and "Key-Value-Coding"!

To show the name in a cell:

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: but how would I create a list of just the names? and then keep the name/url/section trio linked to each other so that when one of the items is selected in the table view the relevant information is passed to the new view controller? I dont know how to extract all the 'name' based items from all the different dictionaries? sorry... :)

Comment: See my answer above. Such a dictionary array can be not only sorted but also conveniently filtered etc. But note that this is not necessary: just set the text of your label in the cell with the correct value from the "name" key from the dictionary.

Comment: Mundi your a chuffing genius!! Ive spent all day trying to get what you did in 5minutes! Im eternally grateful to you, and once I get above 15 reps ill be coming back here and will be clicking like nobodies business on the +1 button. Thanks :)